# calculating total while skipping over certain cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have an example table like this:

```
a    b    c   d
100  0    50  true
0    100  0   false
```

I have named ranges for columns a, b, and c (a_list, b_list, c_list). I'm wondering if its possible to do this:

- if the column d has a true value cell, then the cell values in columns a and b in that row would be added to either a new named range list or to the column c named range list (preferably column c's named range list)

and then if thats possible, calculate each column while skipping the values that were moved to c's named range list.

id like to make this dynamic so i can add as many rows as i need and then it auto calculates.

any help / pointers for this would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for a VBA solution or a formulaic solution?

Comment: @kerwei a formulaic solution. i can calculate the totals of each column, i just dont know how to flag cells to send them to a named range and skip over them during the calculation.

Comment: You can do without the named ranges and either **1)** Use a pivot table or **2)** use `SUMIFS()`